# Enable CSS effect through JS

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-transforms

I have the following code that triggers a certain effect when the mouse pointer is found on the image:

```css
body {
  font: 600 14px/24px "Open Sans", "HelveticaNeue-Light", "Helvetica Neue Light", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, "Lucida Grande", Sans-Serif;
  margin: 12px 0;
}

.card-container {
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 150px;
  perspective: 600;
  position: relative;
  width: 150px;
}

.card {
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  width: 100%;
}

.card:hover {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.card .side {
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  border-radius: 6px;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
}

.card .back {
  background: #eaeaed;
  color: #0087cc;
  line-height: 150px;
  text-align: center;
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="card-container">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="side"><img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/29841/jimmy.jpg" alt="Jimmy Eat World"></div>
    <div class="side back">Jimmy Eat World</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

How do I make an effect start when you press a button and not when you move the mouse over the image?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a CodePen example using JQuery to change the css upon clicking. Might help.

[CodePen Example](https://codepen.io/ThatsIsJustCrazy/pen/JaarpN?editors=1010)

HTML:

```
<div id="divTester">Click me to change color</div>
```

JavaScript (with JQuery):

```
$("body").on("click", "#divTester", function()
  {
     $("#divTester").css("color", "blue");
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

On mousedown will work in combination with a class change. 
Remove the .card:hover from the css and replace it with

```
.card.flip {
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
```

Add the button to the html like:

```
<button id="trigger">Press</button>
```

Than add JS to change the classes. Here's a jQuery sample instead:

```
$('#trigger').mousedown(function() {
    $('.card').addClass('flip');
}).mouseup(function(){
    $('.card').removeClass('flip');
});
```

This will flip all the images within .card div's with one button **press**
The will flip back when button is released. 
You can use the following to keep the flip with button **click**:

```
$('#trigger').click(function() {
    $('.card').toggleClass('flip');
});
```